# Are there any algorithms of non-sequential counting?

Tags: arrays, sorting, iteration

I am looking for a way of iterating over an array non-sequentially. For example, I have an array `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`. You can iterate in ascending order, in descending order, but can you do so without a sequential order? E.g. `11, 14, 15, 19, 16, 12, 13, 18, 17`.

I am specifically looking for an algorithm/mathematical formula to generate indexes from 0 to n **on the fly**. Every number from 0 to n has to come up once and only once.

Alternative solutions I've already considered and why they were discarded:

1. Randomly shuffling the array
   In-place mutation
2. Forming an array of indexes, shuffling it
   Requires additional memory beyond O(1)
3. Generate random numbers from 0 to n, skip duplicates via hashset
   The same issue as above

Comment: Is the number of elements arbitrary? For example, to traverse 2**n-1 elements exhaustively in random (-ish) order, one popular method is to use a linear-feedback shift register (LFSR). In the 1980s some used this for pixel-wise image transitions in PC screensavers.

Comment: @njuffa this is one of the solutions, thanks! Would love to find a way of adopting this to an arbitrary n